# What case do we assign a relativizer representing a subject raised to object?

Tags: grammatical-case

The basic rule I follow is that the case of the relativizer is determined by the role played within the relative clause by the entity it represents.

> Give it to [<sub>OBJ</sub> **whomever** you admire __ most]. (*You admire **him** most.*)
>   Give it to [<sub>SUBJ</sub> **whoever** __ should have it]. (***He*** should have it.)
>   Give it to [<sub>SUBJ</sub> **whoever** you think __ should have it]. (*You think **he** should have it.*)

But what about a 'raised' subject?

> Give it to [<sub>??</sub> **???ever** you want __ to have it].

Does the raised form *You want **him** to have it* govern, or does the underlying role ***He*** HAVE it?

Does the language's growing indifference to persnickety punctilio direct me to *whoever* as the 'unmarked' or 'more natural' form?

Or is Great Mother English sending me the message that I'm pushing the boundaries of the language and ought to rewrite?

Comment: Yay! This is the kind of question I want to see more of here! Because I have *no idea* how to answer it, and so I'm going to learn a lot. Sadly, we only have a handful of true linguists on this site dedicated to "linguists, etymologists, and enthusiasts", so I'm afraid your audience will be small :(  Calling Dr. Lawler!

Comment: I too hope @JohnLawler responds; I imagine he will have something to say about cyclic/postcyclic transformations which will at least clarify my very feeble grasp of that gnarly topic.

Comment: 'Raising' is a matter of semantics. With _to_-infinitivals, the intervening noun or NP in a complex catenative construction like this always belongs syntactically in the matrix; it functions as matrix object, so objective case "whomever" must be the answer. The intervening noun is only 'raised' inasmuch as the verb it relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.

Comment: Raising is both syntax and semantics, like most things in grammar. As to which case to assign, that's a matter between the speaker and their confessor, because it depends on what theoretical church they attend. They might go to Case Grammar of Arc Pair Grammar, for instance. Me, I contribute to the church that says "Don't use _whom_ at all", so there is really no case to assign.

Comment: I'm with @BillJ, even though I can't push the [lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_the_Lizard) in *Alice in Wonderland* out of my head.

Comment: The syntactic status of gap here has nothing whatsoever to do with the semantics of 'raising'. As an exercise in syntax, gap can only be the syntactic object of the matrix verb and hence the pronoun case would strictly speaking be objective. It can be optionally overridden with subjective "whoever" but that's not the point here.

Comment: @BillJ That's begging the question, which is whether the subject of the clausal complement of *want* **is** in fact an object of *want* or is merely represented as an object.

Comment: @StoneyB The subordinate clause is syntactically subjectless, like most non-finites, though it's clearly understood as "whomever". In a diagram, the missing subject would be represented by a gap coreferenced to the object of the matrix verb "want", which would also be a gap as your example shows. It's essentially no different to any other complex catenative construction apart from the complication caused by the 'fused' relative pronoun "whomever" (meaning "the person whom"). I'll see if I can knock out a tree diagram when I get a moment

Comment: @BillJ Don't worry with the diagram, I get you. And don't worry about the *-ever*, either; it works the same with "Give it to him who you think deserves it", "Give to him whom you want to have it", "Give it to him whom you think deserving", right?

Comment: Okay. I agree with your first two, but I think the third one is essentially the same as the first one, so it should be subjective "who". It comprises: _Give it to x_ + _You think (that) x is deserving_, where _x_ is subject of the embedded finite content clause

Comment: @BillJ But that's just the point: we don't say "You think **he** to deserve it", we say "You think **him** to deserve it", just as we say "You want him to deserve it." Where do we draw the line?

Comment: I thought you said earlier that you "got it"! Those first two are ungrammatical. In the 3rd one, the intervening noun "him" is object of "want", but only the _understood_ (i.e. semantic) subject of _to deserve it_.

Comment: You have to take into account that in your last-but-one message, only the 2nd example is a complex catenative with an intervening noun. The other two were just relative clauses with additional embedded content clauses (or _that_-clauses if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll bite. In fact, I think the most reasonable position -- and the one adopted in Relational and Arc Pair grammars -- is that a raised object is in fact an object -- a direct object, in fact. So it can passivize, for instance, (with some verbs, at least):

- *The detective believes that **he** has it*. (no infinitive, no Raising)
- *The detective believes **him** to have it.* (B-Raising to object)
- ***He*** is believed to have it (by the detective). (B-Raising plus Passive of Raised object)

In relational grammars, [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) promotes a 1 in a lower clause to a 2 in a higher clause; and Passive promotes a 2 to a 1 in the same clause. Both of these occur on the same (higher) cycle.

This isn't a matter of "assigning case", however; 
the labial nansal infinx on *whomever* doesn't actually get "assigned" until some milliseconds before the speaker's lips and velic flap coordinate
to produce the /m/.

1's, 2's, and 3's in relational grammars are the basis of the system, and not just a tag that has to be assigned by the grammar. Rather, they refer to the categories Subject, Direct Object, and Indirect Object, respectively. These are the givens in RG, not derived or assigned categories. On the other hand, a lot of the givens in generative grammars aren't needed 
in RG; so it comes in handy.