# What's the syntactic explanation in "Mistakes are likely to happen":

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, construction, predicate-frames, periphrastic-modals

I'm con­fused about this sen­tence con­struc­tion:

> Mis­takes are likely to hap­pen.

I’ve thought of three pos­si­ble ex­pla­na­tions; are any of them
cor­rect?

1. Where *likely* is an ad­jec­tive act­ing as a sub­ject com­ple­ment,
   then *to hap­pen* acts as some type of ad­verb mod­i­fy­ing *likely*?
   (But I don't know what that type would be if so.)
2. *To hap­pen* acts as a sub­ject com­ple­ment, and *likely* as
   an ad­verb of the fi­nite verb (*are*) or the non-fi­nite verb (*to
   hap­pen*).
3. There is an el­lip­sis of *out­comes* be­tween them: *mis­takes
   are likely (out­comes) to hap­pen* where *likely* and *to hap­pen*
   both are ad­jec­tives mod­i­fy­ing *el­lip­sis (out­comes)*, and
   *to hap­pen* is a re­duced rel­a­tive clause of *that might/could
   hap­pen*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119888/discussion-on-question-by-nova-whats-the-syntactic-explanation-in-mistakes-are).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, *(be) likely* is a Raising predicate. That means that the noun phrase subject of *be likely* with a following infinitive complement is not really the subject of *likely*, but of the following infinitive clause.

It's been "Raised" up from its position as infinitive subject to a role in the clause the infinitive is part of. Since *likely* is intransitive, it only has a subject, not an object. So the underlying structure is something like

- *[[For mistakes to happen] is likely]*

where the subject of *is likely* is the whole infinitive clause *for mistakes to happen*.

English doesn't like this kind of sentence, with long complex subjects and short verbs occurring at the end. There are a number of transformations (like Extraposition and Subject Raising) that have the  effect of moving heavy subjects to the end of the sentence, producing distinctive structures. Both are possible with this sentence:

- *It is likely for mistakes to happen.* (Extraposition)
- *Mistakes are likely to happen.* (Subject Raising)

Raised subjects of infinitives don't use *for*, which otherwise marks the subject of the infinitive, while it's still the subject. The *for* is optional with some verbs, disallowed with others, and required when the infinitive clause is subject.

- *I intended for him to mail the letter.*
- *I want (for) him to mail the letter.*
- *For him to mail the letter was the plan.*
- **Him to mail the letter was the plan*

This is the kind of Subject-Raising called the ***A** configuration*, or *A-Raising*.
There is also [B-Raising](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/332589/15299), as in

- *I expect mistakes to happen.*

where the Raised subject becomes the object of a transitive upstairs predicate like *expect*, instead of the subject of an intransitive predicate like *likely*.

There is a vast literature on Subject-Raising, starting with Postal's book *On Raising*. [Here's a collection of handouts and exercises with answers](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) on the contrast between Raising predicates and their converse, which are called **Equi** predicates after the rule they govern.

Answer (score 0):

The **Be** (auxiliary verb) used with the infinitive with to to express futurity, arrangement in advance, or obligation. in this case it conveys "*not surprising and be foreseen*" meaning.

*Mis­takes are likely to hap­pen* = Subject + be +adverb + to Verb

**likely** is adverb that used for expressing emphasis

You can also remove "likely" or use "will" instead of "be + to + verb" but still same meaning:

Mistakes are to happen

Mistakes will happen

Comment: seems make sense too...

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/likely): << _likely_ 
**adjective**  B1
If something is likely, it will probably happen or is expected:
_Do remind me because I'm likely to forget._ >> & cf CED << _unlikely_ **adjective** ... Such unpopular legislation is unlikely to be introduced before the next election. >> & [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/likely) << _likely_  **adjective**  [v-link ADJ to-inf] ... 
_In the meantime the war of nerves seems likely to continue._ >>